# htaccess url rewrite to .php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have the below url

```
http://www.***.org/aaddress.php?state=nm&office_id=852&office_name=CLOVIS&state_name=New%20Mexico
```

I want to change it the below url

```
http://www.*****.org/aaddress-state-nm-office_id-852-office_name-CLOVIS-state_New%20Mexico.php
```

I have used below htaccess code

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule aaddress-state-(.*)-office_id-(.*)-office_name-(.*)-state_name-(.*)\.php aaddress.php?state=$1&office_id=$2&office_name=$3&state_name=$4
```

It's not working, when i click write the address didn't convert to the .php page

My links inside the pages as the 1st link and want to change it as the .php link

Comment: +1 for interesting problem, I will try to come up with a suitable answer.

Answer (score 1):

use this,

```
RewriteRule ^aaddress-state-([^-]+)-office_id-([^-]+)-office_name-([^-]+)-state_name-([^\.]+)\.php$ aaddress.php?state=$1&office_id=$2&office_name=$3&state_name=$4
```

`^` and `$` will match the whole url and `[^-]+` will match anything unless `-` is encountered. And `[^\.]+` will match anything unless `.` is encountered.

This will match `aaddress-state-nm-office_id-852-office_name-CLOVIS-state_name-New Mexico.php`
But **not** `aaddress-state-nm-office_id-852-office_name-CLOVIS-state_New Mexico.php`. **Note** the missing `name-` part in `state_New Mexico` in the later URL.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, still have the same problem, the url appear as it without any change

Comment: See my update. You are passing `state_` but matching `state_name`.

Comment: Thanks again, I can't achieve this yet, there is something wrong but I can't discover it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^aaddress-state-(.*)-office_id-(.*)-office_name-(.*)-state_name-(.*)\.php aaddress.php?state=$1&office_id=$2&office_name=$3&state_name=$4 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it's still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

This is a **recursion based generic solution** which work no matter how long your query string is.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^aaddress\.php$ aaddress-%{QUERY_STRING} [L]

RewriteRule ^([^&]+)&([^&]+)(&.*)?$ $1-$2$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^&])& $1 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^=]+)=([^=]+)(=.*)?$ $1-$2$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^=])= $1 [L]
```

This will internally redirect your example URL to: `/aaddress-state-nm-office_id-852-office_name-CLOVIS-state_name-New+Mexico` by replacing each `&` and `=` of query string to hyphen `-`.